# (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I know this question appears here frequently, but the solutions are either not something I understand yet, or not helping. I have a "Chaplain" entity, which is basically a teacher. Then we have Participants, or, the students. In Participants, I want to store the email address of the Chaplain they are assigned to. They should only ever have one email address in this field. Here's the code in question:

I get this error message:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
>   com.grandcircus.spring.models.ChaplainsEntity column: email (should be
>   mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Here's the code in question:

CHAPLAINENTITY.JAVA

```
package com.grandcircus.spring.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Class description
 *
 * @author Sarah Guarino
 * @version 1.0
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "chaplains", schema = "firststepfreedom", catalog = "")
public class ChaplainsEntity {
    private String id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String phonenumber;
    private String addresslineone;
    private String addresslinetwo;
    private String addresscountry;
    private String addressstate;
    private String addresscounty;
    private String addresscity;
    private String addresszip;
    private int deprecated;
    private int activated;
    private String passcode;
    private Collection<ClassesEntity> classesById;
    private ParticipantsEntity participantsByEmail;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 60)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "phonenumber", nullable = false, length = 25)
    public String getPhonenumber() {
        return phonenumber;
    }

    public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresslineone", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getAddresslineone() {
        return addresslineone;
    }

    public void setAddresslineone(String addresslineone) {
        this.addresslineone = addresslineone;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresslinetwo", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getAddresslinetwo() {
        return addresslinetwo;
    }

    public void setAddresslinetwo(String addresslinetwo) {
        this.addresslinetwo = addresslinetwo;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresscountry", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getAddresscountry() {
        return addresscountry;
    }

    public void setAddresscountry(String addresscountry) {
        this.addresscountry = addresscountry;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addressstate", nullable = false, length = 2)
    public String getAddressstate() {
        return addressstate;
    }

    public void setAddressstate(String addressstate) {
        this.addressstate = addressstate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresscounty", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getAddresscounty() {
        return addresscounty;
    }

    public void setAddresscounty(String addresscounty) {
        this.addresscounty = addresscounty;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresscity", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getAddresscity() {
        return addresscity;
    }

    public void setAddresscity(String addresscity) {
        this.addresscity = addresscity;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresszip", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getAddresszip() {
        return addresszip;
    }

    public void setAddresszip(String addresszip) {
        this.addresszip = addresszip;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "deprecated", nullable = false)
    public int getDeprecated() {
        return deprecated;
    }

    public void setDeprecated(int deprecated) {
        this.deprecated = deprecated;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "activated", nullable = false)
    public int getActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(int activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "passcode", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getPasscode() {
        return passcode;
    }

    public void setPasscode(String passcode) {
        this.passcode = passcode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ChaplainsEntity that = (ChaplainsEntity) o;

        if (phonenumber != that.phonenumber) return false;
        if (deprecated != that.deprecated) return false;
        if (activated != that.activated) return false;
        if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) return false;
        if (firstname != null ? !firstname.equals(that.firstname) : that.firstname != null) return false;
        if (lastname != null ? !lastname.equals(that.lastname) : that.lastname != null) return false;
        if (email != null ? !email.equals(that.email) : that.email != null) return false;
        if (addresslineone != null ? !addresslineone.equals(that.addresslineone) : that.addresslineone != null)
            return false;
        if (addresslinetwo != null ? !addresslinetwo.equals(that.addresslinetwo) : that.addresslinetwo != null)
            return false;
        if (addresscountry != null ? !addresscountry.equals(that.addresscountry) : that.addresscountry != null)
            return false;
        if (addressstate != null ? !addressstate.equals(that.addressstate) : that.addressstate != null) return false;
        if (addresscounty != null ? !addresscounty.equals(that.addresscounty) : that.addresscounty != null)
            return false;
        if (addresscity != null ? !addresscity.equals(that.addresscity) : that.addresscity != null) return false;
        if (addresszip != null ? !addresszip.equals(that.addresszip) : that.addresszip != null) return false;
        if (passcode != null ? !passcode.equals(that.passcode) : that.passcode != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (firstname != null ? firstname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastname != null ? lastname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (phonenumber != null ? addresslineone.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresslineone != null ? addresslineone.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresslinetwo != null ? addresslinetwo.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresscountry != null ? addresscountry.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addressstate != null ? addressstate.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresscounty != null ? addresscounty.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresscity != null ? addresscity.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresszip != null ? addresszip.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + deprecated;
        result = 31 * result + activated;
        result = 31 * result + (passcode != null ? passcode.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "chaplainsByChaplainsid")
    public Collection<ClassesEntity> getClassesById() {
        return classesById;
    }

    public void setClassesById(Collection<ClassesEntity> classesById) {
        this.classesById = classesById;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "email", referencedColumnName = "chaplainemail", nullable = false)
    public ParticipantsEntity getParticipantsByEmail() {
        return participantsByEmail;
    }

    public void setParticipantsByEmail(ParticipantsEntity participantsByEmail) {
        this.participantsByEmail = participantsByEmail;
    }
}
```

PARTICIPANTENTITY.JAVA

```
package com.grandcircus.spring.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Class description
 *
 * @author Sarah Guarino
 * @version 1.0
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "participants", schema = "firststepfreedom", catalog = "")
public class ParticipantsEntity {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String phonenumber;
    private String casenum;
    private int weekscompleted;
    private int weeksneeded;
    private String offensetype;
    private String addresscountry;
    private String addressstate;
    private String addresscounty;
    private String addresscity;
    private String addresszip;
    private int deprecated;
    private int id;
    private String chaplainemail;
    private String addresslinetwo;
    private String passcode;
    private String addresslineone;
    private int activated;
    private Date sentencestart;
    private Date sentenceend;
    private Collection<AppointmentsEntity> appointmentsById;
    private Collection<ChaplainsEntity> participantsByEmail;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 60)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "phonenumber", nullable = false, length = 25)
    public String getPhonenumber() {
        return phonenumber;
    }

    public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "casenum", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getCasenum() {
        return casenum;
    }

    public void setCasenum(String casenum) {
        this.casenum = casenum;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "weekscompleted", nullable = false)
    public int getWeekscompleted() {
        return weekscompleted;
    }

    public void setWeekscompleted(int weekscompleted) {
        this.weekscompleted = weekscompleted;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "weeksneeded", nullable = false)
    public int getWeeksneeded() {
        return weeksneeded;
    }

    public void setWeeksneeded(int weeksneeded) {
        this.weeksneeded = weeksneeded;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "offensetype", nullable = true, length = -1)
    public String getOffensetype() {
        return offensetype;
    }

    public void setOffensetype(String offensetype) {
        this.offensetype = offensetype;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresscountry", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getAddresscountry() {
        return addresscountry;
    }

    public void setAddresscountry(String addresscountry) {
        this.addresscountry = addresscountry;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addressstate", nullable = false, length = 2)
    public String getAddressstate() {
        return addressstate;
    }

    public void setAddressstate(String addressstate) {
        this.addressstate = addressstate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresscounty", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getAddresscounty() {
        return addresscounty;
    }

    public void setAddresscounty(String addresscounty) {
        this.addresscounty = addresscounty;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresscity", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getAddresscity() {
        return addresscity;
    }

    public void setAddresscity(String addresscity) {
        this.addresscity = addresscity;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresszip", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getAddresszip() {
        return addresszip;
    }

    public void setAddresszip(String addresszip) {
        this.addresszip = addresszip;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "deprecated", nullable = false)
    public int getDeprecated() {
        return deprecated;
    }

    public void setDeprecated(int deprecated) {
        this.deprecated = deprecated;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "chaplainemail", nullable = true, length = 60)
    public String getChaplainemail() {
        return chaplainemail;
    }

    public void setChaplainemail(String chaplainemail) {
        this.chaplainemail = chaplainemail;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresslinetwo", nullable = true, length = -1)
    public String getAddresslinetwo() {
        return addresslinetwo;
    }

    public void setAddresslinetwo(String addresslinetwo) {
        this.addresslinetwo = addresslinetwo;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "passcode", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getPasscode() {
        return passcode;
    }

    public void setPasscode(String passcode) {
        this.passcode = passcode;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "addresslineone", nullable = false, length = -1)
    public String getAddresslineone() {
        return addresslineone;
    }

    public void setAddresslineone(String addresslineone) {
        this.addresslineone = addresslineone;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "activated", nullable = false)
    public int getActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(int activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "sentencestart", nullable = false)
    public Date getSentencestart() {
        return sentencestart;
    }

    public void setSentencestart(Date sentencestart) {
        this.sentencestart = sentencestart;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "sentenceend", nullable = false)
    public Date getSentenceend() {
        return sentenceend;
    }

    public void setSentenceend(Date sentenceend) {
        this.sentenceend = sentenceend;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ParticipantsEntity that = (ParticipantsEntity) o;

        if (weekscompleted != that.weekscompleted) return false;
        if (weeksneeded != that.weeksneeded) return false;
        if (deprecated != that.deprecated) return false;
        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (activated != that.activated) return false;
        if (firstname != null ? !firstname.equals(that.firstname) : that.firstname != null) return false;
        if (lastname != null ? !lastname.equals(that.lastname) : that.lastname != null) return false;
        if (email != null ? !email.equals(that.email) : that.email != null) return false;
        if (phonenumber != null ? !phonenumber.equals(that.phonenumber) : that.phonenumber != null) return false;
        if (casenum != null ? !casenum.equals(that.casenum) : that.casenum != null) return false;
        if (offensetype != null ? !offensetype.equals(that.offensetype) : that.offensetype != null) return false;
        if (addresscountry != null ? !addresscountry.equals(that.addresscountry) : that.addresscountry != null)
            return false;
        if (addressstate != null ? !addressstate.equals(that.addressstate) : that.addressstate != null) return false;
        if (addresscounty != null ? !addresscounty.equals(that.addresscounty) : that.addresscounty != null)
            return false;
        if (addresscity != null ? !addresscity.equals(that.addresscity) : that.addresscity != null) return false;
        if (addresszip != null ? !addresszip.equals(that.addresszip) : that.addresszip != null) return false;
        if (chaplainemail != null ? !chaplainemail.equals(that.chaplainemail) : that.chaplainemail != null)
            return false;
        if (addresslinetwo != null ? !addresslinetwo.equals(that.addresslinetwo) : that.addresslinetwo != null)
            return false;
        if (passcode != null ? !passcode.equals(that.passcode) : that.passcode != null) return false;
        if (addresslineone != null ? !addresslineone.equals(that.addresslineone) : that.addresslineone != null)
            return false;
        if (sentencestart != null ? !sentencestart.equals(that.sentencestart) : that.sentencestart != null)
            return false;
        if (sentenceend != null ? !sentenceend.equals(that.sentenceend) : that.sentenceend != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = firstname != null ? firstname.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (lastname != null ? lastname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (phonenumber != null ? phonenumber.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (casenum != null ? casenum.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + weekscompleted;
        result = 31 * result + weeksneeded;
        result = 31 * result + (offensetype != null ? offensetype.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresscountry != null ? addresscountry.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addressstate != null ? addressstate.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresscounty != null ? addresscounty.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresscity != null ? addresscity.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresszip != null ? addresszip.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + deprecated;
        result = 31 * result + id;
        result = 31 * result + (chaplainemail != null ? chaplainemail.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresslinetwo != null ? addresslinetwo.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (passcode != null ? passcode.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (addresslineone != null ? addresslineone.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + activated;
        result = 31 * result + (sentencestart != null ? sentencestart.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (sentenceend != null ? sentenceend.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "participantsByParticipantid")
    public Collection<AppointmentsEntity> getAppointmentsById() {
        return appointmentsById;
    }

    public void setAppointmentsById(Collection<AppointmentsEntity> appointmentsById) {
        this.appointmentsById = appointmentsById;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "participantsByEmail")
    public Collection<ChaplainsEntity> getParticipantsByEmail() {
        return participantsByEmail;
    }

    public void setParticipantsByEmail(Collection<ChaplainsEntity> participantsByEmail) {
        this.participantsByEmail = participantsByEmail;
    }
}
```

CHAPLAINENTITY hibernate xm

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.grandcircus.spring.models.ChaplainsEntity" table="chaplains" schema="firststepfreedom">
        <id name="id">
            <column name="id" sql-type="varchar(10)" length="10"/>
        </id>
        <property name="firstname">
            <column name="firstname" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="lastname">
            <column name="lastname" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="email">
            <column name="email" sql-type="varchar(60)" length="60"/>
        </property>
        <property name="phonenumber">
            <column name="phonenumber" sql-type="varchar(25)" length="25"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresslineone">
            <column name="addresslineone" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresslinetwo">
            <column name="addresslinetwo" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresscountry">
            <column name="addresscountry" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addressstate">
            <column name="addressstate" sql-type="varchar(2)" length="2"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresscounty">
            <column name="addresscounty" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresscity">
            <column name="addresscity" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresszip">
            <column name="addresszip" sql-type="varchar(10)" length="10"/>
        </property>
        <property name="deprecated">
            <column name="deprecated" sql-type="int(1)"/>
        </property>
        <property name="activated">
            <column name="activated" sql-type="int(1)"/>
        </property>
        <property name="passcode">
            <column name="passcode" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="participantsByEmail" class="com.grandcircus.spring.models.ParticipantsEntity">
            <column name="email"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <set name="classesById" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="chaplainsid"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many not-found="ignore" class="com.grandcircus.spring.models.ClassesEntity"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

PARTICIPANTENTITY hibernate xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.grandcircus.spring.models.ParticipantsEntity" table="participants" schema="firststepfreedom">
        <id name="id">
            <column name="id" sql-type="int(11) unsigned zerofill"/>
        </id>
        <property name="firstname">
            <column name="firstname" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="lastname">
            <column name="lastname" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="email">
            <column name="email" sql-type="varchar(60)" length="60"/>
        </property>
        <property name="phonenumber">
            <column name="phonenumber" sql-type="varchar(25)" length="25"/>
        </property>
        <property name="casenum">
            <column name="casenum" sql-type="varchar(45)" length="45"/>
        </property>
        <property name="weekscompleted">
            <column name="weekscompleted" sql-type="int(3)"/>
        </property>
        <property name="weeksneeded">
            <column name="weeksneeded" sql-type="int(3)"/>
        </property>
        <property name="offensetype">
            <column name="offensetype" sql-type="tinytext" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresscountry">
            <column name="addresscountry" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addressstate">
            <column name="addressstate" sql-type="varchar(2)" length="2"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresscounty">
            <column name="addresscounty" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresscity">
            <column name="addresscity" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresszip">
            <column name="addresszip" sql-type="varchar(10)" length="10"/>
        </property>
        <property name="deprecated">
            <column name="deprecated" sql-type="int(1)"/>
        </property>
        <property name="chaplainemail">
            <column name="chaplainemail" sql-type="varchar(60)" length="60" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresslinetwo">
            <column name="addresslinetwo" sql-type="tinytext" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="passcode">
            <column name="passcode" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addresslineone">
            <column name="addresslineone" sql-type="tinytext"/>
        </property>
        <property name="activated">
            <column name="activated" sql-type="int(1)"/>
        </property>
        <property name="sentencestart">
            <column name="sentencestart" sql-type="date"/>
        </property>
        <property name="sentenceend">
            <column name="sentenceend" sql-type="date"/>
        </property>
        <set name="appointmentsById" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="participantid"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many not-found="ignore" class="com.grandcircus.spring.models.AppointmentsEntity"/>
        </set>
        <set name="participantsByEmail" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="email"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many not-found="ignore" class="com.grandcircus.spring.models.ChaplainsEntity"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in the `ChaplainsEntity` class, you've mapped the `email` column to two different fields - `email` and `participantsByEmail`.

This is an error, because if you had a `ChaplainsEntity` object with different values of `email` in those two fields, Hibernate wouldn't know which one to save in the `email` column.  The only way this could be acceptable would be if this column were read-only from the Hibernate point of view - that is, you'll never ask Hibernate to insert or update this value.

Comment: Okay, so given the setup that I have, which would you recommend changing? I need chaplains to be able to change their email, while also changing the chaplain's email in the participant table to reassign them if needed, so removing the ability to change either columns is a no-no for me.

Comment: Do you store it in two different places in the database?

Comment: What do you mean? In the participants table I have: email (which is the participants email) and chaplainemail (which is the chaplain they'yre assigned to). In the chaplains email, I have email (which is the chaplains email). Should I change it to something like chaplainemail, participantemail, and assignedchaplain or something, or am I way off?

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't have chaplainemail in the participants table - you should just have the identifier of the chaplain.  Otherwise, your database might get into a state where chaplainemail has a different value from the email column in the chaplains table.  Or, if  you need them to sometimes have different values, then you've got the Hibernate mapping wrong.

Comment: It's my understanding that that was the POINT of a foreign key in the first place? So when the chaplain updates his email, all the foreign associations in the participant table would update with it. I cannot use the ID, because chaplains are assigned an ID as part of the program, it is not auto-gen, and it has the last four of their SS# in it, so I don't want that info being passed around a lot.

Comment: No, a foreign key doesn't automatically update stuff for you.  If you don't want to use the "chaplain id" as the primary key for your chaplain table, you could add an auto-generated column and use _that_ as the key instead.

Comment: And I'm assuming I should have duplicate "id" columns either? Because they both have id columns ._.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147536/discussion-between-dawood-ibn-kareem-and-sarah-guarino).